# Escaping parentheses from HTML with Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to get the value of some data that's in parentheses. Here's my Javascript code.

```
var info = $('.printedsubtext:first');
re = /\((.*)\)/i;
console.log(info.match(re)[1]);​
```

.printedsubtext looks like this (notice that there's an empty div right after so I'm selecting the first occurrence)

```
<div class="printedsubtext" style="margin-top: 10px;"> 
<strong>Merchant SKU:</strong> 155687<br> 
<strong>ASIN:</strong> B009NFT9PK<br>
<strong>Listing ID:</strong> 1009MIKWRIP<br>
<strong>Order-Item ID:</strong> 02975468341162<br>
<strong>Condition:</strong> Used - Good<br>
<strong>Comments:</strong> Publisher: Thomas Y. Crowell&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;Date of Publication: 1973&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;Binding: hard cover&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;Edition: &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;Condition: Good/Fair&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;Description: (M481)&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;<br>
<div class="printedsubtext" style="margin-top: 10px;">
</div>
</div>
```

I want the code to print M481 into the console.

This, however, produces a syntax error. For some reason, it works if I replace info to something like this

```
var info = "Cats make (me) happy";
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of making up an XY problem in the title, just report the goal/problem. This question has nothing to do with parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match` is a method of a string; you are invoking it from a jQuery collection. Try using the text of the selected elements.

If you want to include HTML in the search, you should use:

```
var info = $('.printedsubtext:first').html();
```

If you only want to consider text nodes, use:

```
var info = $('.printedsubtext:first').text();
```

Comment: var info = $('.printedsubtext:first').html();

Comment: `var info = $('.printedsubtext:first').html();
re = /\((.*)\)/i ;
console.log(info.match(re)[1]);​` still produces a syntax error unfortunately :(

Comment: or var info=$(".printedsubtext:first").text()

Comment: @user2036066 What error? The fiddle I have posted works correctly, doesn't it?

Comment: @Asad Hmm, I copied and pasted the code from the fiddle and now it works. Thank you so much for the help! I'll accept your answer asap

Comment: @user2036066 In the code snippet you have provided, there is three extra characters at the end: `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX character`, together with two control characters. Copy paste error, probably.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var txt = $(".printedsubtext").text();
re = txt.match(/\((.+)\)/);
alert(re[1]);
```